# Water stream push force too small

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play Minecraft 1.14.4 vanilla on a server I host for a few friends and family.
Server version is 1.14.4 as I confirmed from the server log:

> Starting minecraft server version 1.14.4

I am in the process of building an [ice farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8A06bX2f3Y) that makes use of water streams that transport the player along a horizontal route.

As water push strength got reduced in 1.13, each segment of the water stream is 5 blocks long and has ice below it. However, the force is still not strong enough to keep the player moving.

I built the same setup in my local creative test world. Strangely, in this world the water streams work fine.
I disabled all datapacks that were in use to ensure that they do not create the issue.

I verified that the issue is related to the world itself, not to the multiplayer aspect, by downloading the world save and testing locally. The issue persists. I also tried switching to creative which does not make a difference. Further, I tried multiple locations within the world - all to no avail. There seems to be some issue with the world save itself - I am at a loss.

The world itself was created in version 1.13.2 and later, with the release of 1.14.4 converted to the recent format.

This is my test setup that works fine:
[image: Waterstream with ice]
As you can see, I tried with different types of ice below the water. They all work as expected. I also tried them as a single block width channel which worked fine.

This is the setup on the server which does not work:
[image: Water stream with ice]
For debugging purposes I also tried reducing the length of the waterstream to two blocks - to no avail. Travelling speed is as slow the entire time as it would usually be on the last few blocks.
Am I missing something here?

After more debugging, the issue seems to berelated to the `level.dat` file. This is how I tested it:

1. Create a new world
2. Replace the `level.dat`
3. build a water stream

The `level.dat` I used can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15wW-R_T3oNkd0UK6Gxvaymhn-DdNhn2U).

*Note:* To clarify: The player shall be moved by itself, there are no boats inplay here - see the video above for an example.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! Thank you for your well thought-out, detailed question. Though I personally don't know the answer, hopefully someone in the community can help.

Comment: @Gigazelle Thanks for the warm welcome. I know how important it is to think a question through, I am happy you noticed. I hope it fits the scope on arcade.

Comment: You're using a 3 blocks wide water stream in the test world and a 1 wide one on the server? Then that's probably your problem. Boats are wider than 1 block. Also, sometimes lag can do weird stuff to boats, minecarts, horses etc., but if you locally host the server, there shouldn't be much difference.

Comment: @FabianRöling There are no boats at play here, the player is pushed by itself. I clarified this point in the question. Also, channel width has no effect on the speed, I just tested that to verify

Comment: What happens if you build the same thing block by block the same in a new world at the same coordinates? This definitely seems like a bug, but I don't know if it's something in the world or maybe a rotation/location thing. Also, can you upload the two worlds you tried, so that I can test it as well?

Comment: @FabianRöling During some debugging today I found that the issue seems to relate to my `level.dat`. I created a new world where the water stream worked fine, then replaced the `level.dat` file with the one of my server and the stream was broken. I am looking a little deeper into it and see wether I can find something. NBTExplorer did not yield much - my current trace: The Version property of the level file still says "1.13.2", maybe there was an issue when switching the server versions back then.

Comment: I can also share the file, sharing the world would be to much - it has about 4G's. Is there a preferred service for file sharing on arqade?

Comment: There is no standard, as long as it's reliable and doesn't use ad redirection, forces login or other weird stuff like that. I always use Google Drive.

Comment: Is the issue with the difference in width of the water streams?

Comment: @Corsaka No, there is no difference with different widths. I also recently tried creating a new world and then copying everything that is different from the level file in the broken world to the new one, then replacing it. But this also does not fix the problem.

Comment: I haven't played minecraft too recently, but the local client has a few tools for getting old worlds up to speed. I do not know their names off the top of my head, but have you tried useing them on your local copy of the world? perhaps one of them will solve your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After more debugging, the issue seems to berelated to the level.dat file. This is how tested it:
>
> 1. Create a new world
> 2. Replace the `level.dat`
> 3. build a water stream

Doing the above copies your *armor*. Take off your `Depth Strider III` boots. They are the issue.

I copied the `.dat` file and on reload my character was in a different spot, had differnet equipment on, and the inventory was differnet. So I looked at the boots, saw the enchantment, and took them off. Then my water stream test worked just fine.

Comment: I am facepalming so hard right now! If that really is the reason, I can't believe I did not check that :) thank you for the hint. I will check it out as soon as I can. Until then have a good start into 2020

Comment: Can confirm. I mined 250k ice in an ice farm without water stream. Others did as well. This oversight wasted hours! Thank! you!